# Fitted function - Which is better to use?

Tags: statistics, approximation, estimation

So I have some data for program running time, that follows a power law relation aN^b. I log-log plotted the data and saw that it became a straight line, so I calculated the slope of this line to get b, and then calculated a using one of my data points.

I also did a version where I used FindFit in Mathemathica, to find a best fit for the log10 version of the data in y = kx + m form.

If I test these two functions and compare to my data, the **Mathemathica generated version is more accurate for lower N values**(input-size).
The f**unction I calculated is less accurate for lower N's, but more accurate for higher N's.**

It makes sense to me to use the one I calculated, because it's more important that the equation is correct for large N values in this case.

N**ow my question is:
Is it better mathemathically to use the mathemathica equation that is more accurate for most of my data, or the equation I calculated that is more correct for high N values?
I was thinking maybe it's better to use the mathemathica one and the error should be calculated using statistics?**

Edit: data on a log-log plot
[image: The data line in a log-log plot]

For my calculation of the slope i used the 2 farthest data points and calculated the slope of this straight line:
[image]

Then I calculated the constant a in aN^b using the data point where N = 65536 and T = 4630.283.
My calculated equation: [image]

The Mathemathica generated equation:
[image]

Comment: How did you calculate the slope of this line? Can you show us your plot? What did the functions you got look like?

Comment: Updated it now.

Comment: No expert in Mathematica, but probabliy the fit generated with Mathematica is optimal in the least square sense for all your data. However, if you're interested in the runtime of your code for large values, I would prefer your method. For small values of $n$ the runtime might not depend solely on your computation but maybe also on initialization, I/O, etc. This influences the runtime and goes into the Mathematica calculation. If you're mostly interested in the runtime of your algorithm without initialization, allocation, I/O, use your approximation.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think you're right, I will use my approximation.

Comment: And do also consider this: As @sonystarmap said mathematica probably used least squares to fit the exponential curve to your data. But you might want to do a linear regression (also least squares) but on the log/log data, and then convert the result to an exponential curve. (This is basically what you did, but only with 2 points).

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will look into doing that.

Comment: Also, if you're only interested in large $n$ values, have you tried just throwing away the bottom half of your data and letting Mathematica try to find a fit on just the top half?